# Getting cleanup badge?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

I see cleanup badge on my user page and it say :

> **how to get it :**
>   First Rollback

that's all, not much info to help for trying to get this badge.

Do I need to back under a revision state under an edit page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very similar Q&A at Meta Stack Exchange that should provide the answer to this.

The accepted answer to [How can I get the "cleanup" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56287/215590) says:

> A rollback involves using a command that is called "Rollback". It
>   shows up when a post that you have edited has the most recent revision
>   by another user. Rolling back will return the post to the last
>   revision that you had made to the post. It requires edit permissions
>   on other people's posts, but is always available on your own posts.
>   For example, I have just edited your post. You should now have an
>   option to "rollback" in the same area that you can flag or edit.
>
> It can also be achieved on a post by rolling back to any revision, by
>   accessing the revision history of a post that has multiple revisions
>   (when you have edit privileges). The option "rollback" can be used to
>   revert to any specific revision, and this qualifies for the badge as
>   well. You can see this
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2625178/revisions) on one of
>   your own questions.